# Cannot find table details in mysql information_schema

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I am working on an assignment where I am supposed to find all of the tables in information_schema of a "blank" database. I can do this in either MySQL or PostgreSQL. I chose MySQL. So, I have identified all of the tables:

1. CHARACTER_SETS
2. COLLATIONS
3. COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY
4. COLUMNS
5. COLUMN_PRIVILEGES
6. INDEX_STATISTICS
7. KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
8. PROFILING
9. ROUTINES
10. SCHEMATA
11. SCHEMA_PRIVILEGES
12. STATISTICS
13. TABLES
14. TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
15. TABLE_PRIVILEGES
16. TABLE_STATISTICS
17. TRIGGERS
18. USER_PRIVILEGES
19. VIEWS

Now, I have to find details about those tables. For example, primary key definitions, table columns, foreign keys, trigger actions, etc.

The problem that I am running into, however, is that none of these tables list any primary keys or foreign keys or constraints, etc.

Am I misinterpreting? Or can this information be found anywhere? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be looking in `table_constraints`.

```
SELECT `table_name`, `constraint_name`, `constraint_type` 
FROM `information_schema`.`table_constraints` 
WHERE `table_schema` = 'yourdbname';
```

That will get you the constraint names and types. If you want more detail you'll need to join on `key_column_usage`.

```
SELECT c.`table_schema`, c.`table_name`, c.`constraint_name`,
c.`constraint_type`, GROUP_CONCAT(k.`column_name` ORDER BY `ordinal_position`) AS 'constraint columns',
CONCAT(k.`referenced_table_name`, '(', GROUP_CONCAT(`referenced_column_name` ORDER BY `position_in_unique_constraint`),')') AS 'references' 
FROM `information_schema`.`table_constraints` c 
JOIN `information_schema`.`key_column_usage` k USING (`constraint_name`, `table_name`) 
WHERE c.`table_schema` = 'yourdbname' 
GROUP BY `table_schema`,`table_name`,`constraint_name`,`constraint_type`,`referenced_table_name`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the command `DESCRIBE table;`?

If there is a primary key you will see...

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Then there is no primary key.  It's not a good idea but it is possible.